# ImportError: cannot import name 'PasswordGenerator' from 'password_generator'

Tags: python, importerror, password-generator

ImportError: cannot import name 'PasswordGenerator' from 'password_generator'

i found this error in my python project.
i installed PasswordGenerator in administrative command prompt

how to resolve it

Comment: Did you install it with `pip install random-password-generator`?

Comment: i installed it wth pip install 'password_generator

Comment: well, try importing random-password-generator.